# Unable to pass receiver mail id using intent in android

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I have been trying to pass some text using  " Intent.ACTION_SEND" but I want the same text to send using Whatsapp, Gmail etc . I tried using the below code.

```
     String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
     Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
     sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"hei@gmail.com"});
     sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "subject"));
```

It is working fine I am able to pass the same String using Whatsapp and Gmail but I need to pass receiver mail id to pass along with it..I tried passing as above but nothing happens. The mail id is not getting populated . Please help !!

Comment: I've tried you code and its working as expected. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Try sending using Gmail I want the text as well as the receiver mail id "hei@gmail" to get populated in the receiver's field in gmail @Evgeny Maltsev